# Cucumber-JVM ant task

Tags: java, ant, groovy, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

How do i tell ant to execute all cucumber tests (features, implementations) in a folder?

I'm stuck using this example

```
<target name="runcukes" depends="compile-test">
        <mkdir dir="target/cucumber-junit-report"/>
        <java classname="cucumber.cli.Main" fork="true" failonerror="false" resultproperty="cucumber.exitstatus">
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="junit:target/cucumber-junit-report/allcukes.xml"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="pretty"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="html:target/cucumber-html-report"/>
            <arg value="--glue"/>
            <arg value="cucumber.examples.java.helloworld"/>
            <arg value="src/test/resources"/>
        </java>

        <junitreport todir="target/cucumber-junit-report">
            <fileset dir="target/cucumber-junit-report">
                <include name="allcukes.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="target/cucumber-junit-report"/>
        </junitreport>

        <fail message="Cucumber failed">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="${cucumber.exitstatus}" arg2="0"/>
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Usage: java cucumber.cli.Main [options] [ [FILE|DIR][:LINE[:LINE]*] ]+

Options:

```
-g, --glue PATH Where glue code (step definitions and hooks) is loaded from.
-f, --format FORMAT[:OUT] How to format results. Goes to STDOUT unless OUT is specified.
                                Available formats: junit, html, pretty, progress, json, json-pretty.
-t, --tags TAG_EXPRESSION Only run scenarios tagged with tags matching TAG_EXPRESSION.
-n, --name REGEXP Only run scenarios whose names match REGEXP.
-d, --dry-run Skip execution of glue code.
-m, --monochrome Don't colour terminal output.
    --dotcucumber Where to write out runtime information.
-v, --version Print version.
-h, --help You're looking at it.
```

In your case - change the `<arg value="src/test/resources"/>` to directory you want to run against. Note that you can specify multiple individual files and directories space-separated.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem and solved by declaring top package name like in you case the package name is "cucumber.examples.java.helloworld" Just declare only cucumber like this

```
 <arg value="--glue"/>
 <arg value="cucumber"/>
```

in you ant task. It's working at me end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the build file provided along with the samples from github, you can write your own build file.

Try running the Junit test file from ant using ant's **Junit** task. Set "format" of   "@Cucumber.Options" annotation to point to the directory having your features.

Example

To run the Junit test,add the following target to your build file,

```
<junit printsummary="yes" failureproperty="junit.failure">

<classpath refid="id_of_the_path_to_find_JARS/.class files"></classpath>

<test name="com.example.YourTestClass" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result" >
<formatter type="plain"/>
<formatter type="xml"/>
</test>

</junit>
```

The Juint test specified in the `<test name="com.example.YourTestClass" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result" >` will be executed. The **YourTestClass.java** will look like this...

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@Cucumber.Options(format = {"html:target/cucumber-html","junit:target/cucumber-junit/Webpage.xml"},features = "src/test/features")
public class YourTestClass {

}
```

All the feature files kept in **src/test/features** will run while executing the build file